# need a bittorrent daemon

Tags: linux, bittorrent, daemon

I'm building a Ubuntu server for the house.  I want to centralize torrents.  what I'm looking for is something that runs as a service (daemon) that has 3 folders to configure.

1. Actively downloading torrents - this will be a folder where I can just drop a torrent file and the service picks it up and starts downloading
2. Seeding torrents - when a torrent is finished downloading, the actual torrent file is moved to this folder.  when the torrent file is deleted from this folder, the daemon stops seeding
3. download folder - the folder where it drops files as they are downloading.

Additional features would be nice, like a web or console based screen where I can see the status of the downloads and such, but the fact that it can run as a deamon without someone logged in is a deal breaker.

Let me know if you know of anything.

Comment: transmission looks promising, has anyone used it?  i can't find a manual so im not sure if it will do what i want

Comment: Transmission is good, but I know something better - gonna leave that as an answer below...

Answer (score 7):

For pure daemon usage on a headless server, [rtorrent](https://rakshasa.github.io/rtorrent/) would be the client I would go to.  It's command-line and very feature complete, although it's not the easiest thing to set up being purely command line.  There are numerous web interfaces to rtorrent as well, although, again, they don't seem to be very easy to set up.

For GUI clients, I prefer [qBittorrent](https://www.qbittorrent.org/) because it works very well and has a good interface.  It has a web interface, too, although I currently do not use it.

Deluge is alright, but when I was using it 2-3 years ago I found it would stall constantly and the performance was significantly less than other clients.  I cannot say if this is true today, however.

Transmission works pretty well, but always seemed very bare-bones to me.

My personal experiences with the devs and admins on the uTorrent forums (I found them insulting, foul-mouthed, condescending, arrogant, and self-entitled) have led me to wholly shun the program.  I no longer recommend it on any platform regardless of how mature uTorrent is.  Indeed, I tend to recommend *anything else*.

Answer (score 3):

You wanna use [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/). It's awesome.

From the [About Deluge](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/About) page:

- Core/UI split allowing Deluge to run as a daemon
- Connect remotely to the Deluge daemon
- Web UI
- Console UI
- GTK+ UI
- BitTorrent Protocol Encryption
- Mainline DHT
- Local Peer Discovery (aka LSD)
- FAST protocol extension
- µTorrent Peer Exchange
- UPnP and NAT-PMP
- Proxy support
- Web seed
- Private Torrents
- Global and per-torrent speed limits
- Configurable bandwidth scheduler
- Password protection
- RSS (via Plugin)
- Other  libtorrent features
- And much more!

It also will do all the folder stuff you specified!

Deluge is included in the default apt repos on Ubuntu, so you can just run the following to install it:

```
 sudo apt-get install deluge deluge-webui deluge-torrent deluge-gtk deluge-console deluge-web
```

You can configure it via the GTK interface and then run it as a daemon. The [Deluge FAQ](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Faq) has a fair bit of useful config documentation you'll likely want to read.

PS - I have nothing to with the Deluge team, I just love great software.

Answer (score 3):

Allmost all GNU/Linux torrents have daemons these days. I personally use [Transmission](http://transmissionbt.com), but you can also use [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org), [uTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/complete?os=linux) and many others.