# BitTorrent daemon with IPv6 web interface?

Tags: linux, bittorrent, ipv6

I'm looking for a BitTorrent daemon (for Debian) that

- has a webinterface which
- can be accessed via IPv6.

[Transmission](https://www.transmissionbt.com/) and [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) come to mind, but both of them seem to lack IPv6 support in the webinterface; see the corresponding [transmission](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/2236) and [deluge](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/ticket/1130) tickets.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Because of https://superuser.com/questions/309878/need-a-bittorrent-daemon, I thought this site was appropriate. Can we move the question or will we just close it?

Comment: That's a 4 year old question. There was no softwarerecs back then as far as I know.

Comment: I've recreated the question at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30700/bittorrent-daemon-with-ipv6-web-interface.

Comment: Great. Please delete this one.

Comment: I tried, but cannot because it already has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

µTorrent WebUI looks to support IPv6 now https://forum.utorrent.com/topic/49588-%C2%B5torrent-webui/

don't use it for piracy though! ;)